# Problems playing stereo data using GStreamer AppSrc element

Tags: c, audio, gstreamer

I have a program that plays float audio samples using the AppSrc GStreamer element. I have adapted the code from [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/short-cutting-the-pipeline.html).

This is the function that I use to push data into the AppSrc:

```
static gboolean push_data (CustomData *data) {
  GstBuffer *buffer;
  GstFlowReturn ret;
  GstMapInfo map;
  SAMPLE *raw;
  gint num_frames = CHUNK_SIZE / sizeof(SAMPLE) / data->channels;

  /* Create a new empty buffer */
  buffer = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc (CHUNK_SIZE);

  /* Set its timestamp and duration */
  GST_BUFFER_TIMESTAMP (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale (data->playback_offset, GST_SECOND, data->samplerate);
  GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale (CHUNK_SIZE / data->channels / sizeof(SAMPLE), GST_SECOND, data->samplerate);

  /* Generate some psychodelic waveforms */
  gst_buffer_map (buffer, &map, GST_MAP_WRITE);
  raw = (SAMPLE *) map.data;

  memcpy(raw, data->samples + data->playback_offset, MIN(data->size - data->playback_offset, CHUNK_SIZE));

  gst_buffer_unmap (buffer, &map);
  data->playback_offset += num_frames;

  /* Push the buffer into the appsrc */
  g_signal_emit_by_name (data->app_source, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);

  /* Free the buffer now that we are done with it */
  gst_buffer_unref (buffer);

  if (ret != GST_FLOW_OK) {
    /* We got some error, stop sending data */
    return FALSE;
  }

  if (data->playback_offset >= data->size)
  {
      puts("Reached end of sample.");
      gst_app_src_end_of_stream ((GstAppSrc *) data->app_source);
      g_main_loop_quit (data->main_loop);
  }

  return TRUE;
}
```

I also set the element's CAPS to the sample format before using the pipeline:

```
  /* Configure appsrc */
  gst_audio_info_set_format (&info, GST_AUDIO_FORMAT_F32, (gint) data.samplerate, (gint) data.channels, NULL);
  audio_caps = gst_audio_info_to_caps (&info);
  g_object_set (data.app_source, "caps", audio_caps, "format", GST_FORMAT_TIME, NULL);
  g_signal_connect (data.app_source, "need-data", G_CALLBACK (start_feed), &data);
  g_signal_connect (data.app_source, "enough-data", G_CALLBACK (stop_feed), &data);
```

(full program [here](https://pastebin.com/raw/TzbW9JxB))

The program works as expected for mono samples.
However, when I try to play a stereo sample (`data.channels` being set to 2 and stereo data being read), the sample is played at half the speed and garbled.

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Comment: set your buffer duration to the following:
GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer) = gst_util_uint64_scale_int (GST_SECOND, CHUNK_SIZE/data->channels, data->samplerate); and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, Prabhakar. There seems to be an issue with GST_BUFFER_DURATION not working in general, since even doing `GST_BUFFER_DURATION (buffer) = 0;` has no effect. Do you have any idea as to why this may be?